# JSON obj property with same name as JS keyword "all"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access a property that is being returned through an ajax call and my JSON object that is being returned has a property that I need to access that has the same name as the keyword "all". I can't seem to find a way to be able to access this property field because it assumes I am using the keyword when I try to access the property "forecast.main.clouds.all" here is an example of the object that is being returned through the ajax call.

```
{
"coord":{"lon":-93.3,"lat":37.26}, 
"weather":
 [ {
     "id":800,
      "main":"Clear",
      "description":"clear sky",
      "icon":"01d"
   } ], 
 "base":"stations", 
 "main": 
  {
    "temp":64.4, 
    "pressure":1019, 
    "humidity":36, 
    "temp_min":64.4, 
    "temp_max":64.4 
   }, 
  "visibility":16093, 
  "wind":{"speed":9.17,"deg":330}, 
  "clouds":{"all":1}, 
  "dt":1540759920, 
  "sys":{ 
        "type":1,
        "id":1661,
        "message":0.0041,
        "country":"US",
        "sunrise":1540730075,
        "sunset":1540768719 
      }, 
  "id":420021920, 
  "name":"Springfield", 
  "cod":200
```

}

Comment: sorry, the correct call to the property would be "forecast.clouds.all", no .main.

Comment: You can edit your question to make the correction.

Comment: Have you tried `forecast.clouds['all']`?

Comment: But `all` is **not** a JavaScript keyword.

Comment: What exactly is going on that led you to believe that you're having a problem caused by improper use of a keyword?

Comment: `console.log(obj.clouds.all)` works fine here.

Comment: because I'm getting an error in the console. I wouldn't post this question if I wasn't getting a direct error from the browser.

Comment: @TaylorShmaylor, maybe you should pst the error or create a runnable snippet (use the `<>` button in the editor) that reproduces the error.

Comment: Post some code then. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I would use .all, but it's not working, that's why I posted the question. Any suggestions would be appreciated instead of incorrectly insisting that it will work when it is not.

Comment: If you don't post the actual error nobody will be able to help you. It is absolutely 100% true that `.all` works just fine and that the word "all" is not a keyword. You're clearly encountering *some* kind of problem, but the conclusion you've reached is simply incorrect.

Comment: @user10575874, could you please quote the exact error message you are getting in the console when trying to call `obj.clouds.all`?

Answer (score 0):

Access using the bracket notations `forcast['clouds']['all']`.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It just works</strike> `all` is not a [keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) in JavaScript, and based on the code pieces you have shown, no problems seem to arise:

```js
var forecast={
"coord":{"lon":-93.3,"lat":37.26}, 
"weather":
 [ {
     "id":800,
      "main":"Clear",
      "description":"clear sky",
      "icon":"01d"
   } ], 
 "base":"stations", 
 "main": 
  {
    "temp":64.4, 
    "pressure":1019, 
    "humidity":36, 
    "temp_min":64.4, 
    "temp_max":64.4 
   }, 
  "visibility":16093, 
  "wind":{"speed":9.17,"deg":330}, 
  "clouds":{"all":1}, 
  "dt":1540759920, 
  "sys":{ 
        "type":1,
        "id":1661,
        "message":0.0041,
        "country":"US",
        "sunrise":1540730075,
        "sunset":1540768719 
      }, 
  "id":420021920, 
  "name":"Springfield", 
  "cod":200 
};
console.log(forecast.clouds.all);
```

What is the question?

Comment: @Turnip: I was showing that putting OP's question and comments together results in fine-behaving code.

Comment: Do that with a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Turnip How can I put an executable snippet into a comment? Keep in mind that OP insists *I'm getting an error in the console. I wouldn't post this question if I wasn't getting a direct error from the browser.*

Comment: Use JSFiddle or CodePen etc. Your post doesn't attempt to answer the question. It just states that the code works.